# Using Twython to correctly navigate a users tweets

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am trying to use Twython to retrieve the last tweet an account makes.
My current code is:

```
try:
   user_timeline = twitter.get_user_timeline(screen_name='Twitter')
except TwythonError as e:
   print e

for tweets in user_timeline:
   print tweets['text'].encode('utf-8')
```

However, while I do get the tweets in the desired text format, the for loop I am using returns the users last 20 tweets. I only need the last tweet made by the user.

I am a complete Noob to Python, so any help is appreciated.
I have had a difficult time tracking down example code so any pointers on that, too, would be appreciated.

Comment: Which one, first in current output, or last?

Comment: you can try `tweet = user_timeline[0]; print tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Yes! This worked, thank you kind internet stranger :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the count argument in the call to the get_user_timeline function. It should works.

```
try:
    user_timeline = twitter.get_user_timeline(screen_name='Twitter', count=1)
except TwythonError as e:
   print e

for tweets in user_timeline:
   print tweets['text'].encode('utf-8')
```